# Using linq to find any of multiple values of List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, linq

My list looks like: `List<List<string>>`.

I need to check if any of the nested list first value is equal to some values.

This is what I did and it working:

```
if (myList.Any(sb => 
               sb.First() == "Value1" || 
               sb.First() == "Value2" || 
               sb.First() == "Value3" || 
               sb.First() == "Value4"))
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make the query in way that don't repeat the `sb.First()`?
Is my way of implementing has influence on performance?

Comment: Create an array of all possible values i.e. `var array = new[]{"Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"}`, then check `if (myList.Any(sb => array.Contains(sb.First()))`?

Comment: If `myList` is of type `IList<T>`, it will just call `sb[0] == "Value1"`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an array of values and check if it contains whatever is in `sb.First()`, like this:

```
if (myList.Any(sb => 
           new HashSet<string> {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"}.IndexOf(sb.First()) > -1)
```

Comment: How about: `new string[]` -> `HashSet<string>` ?

Comment: Yeah, a hash set might be better.

Comment: If you are going to use a hash set then you better accept one of the answers that suggest it instead of my suggestion for an array...

Answer (score 1):

You could first create a `HashSet` to contain the values:

```
var container = new HashSet<string> {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"};
```

and then use it as:

```
if (myList.Any(sb => container.Contains(sb.First()))){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var matches = new HashSet<string>() { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4" };

myList.Select(sb => sb.FirstOrDefault()).
       Any(st => matches.Contains(st));
```

Should do it, using a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) to improve string comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You could make also this:

```
        if (l.Any(x =>
        {
            var sb = x.First();
            return sb == "Value1" ||
                   sb == "Value2" ||
                   sb == "Value3" ||
                   sb == "Value4";
        }))
        {
            // true
        }
```